# sync event with google calendar from android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent, google-calendar-api

im trying to add events to android calendar
which will sync these events automaticlly to google calendar
but its not working !!
events added manualy do sync but events added from my code, appears in calendar but dont sync with google calendar why???

this is my add event code

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
event.put("calendar_id", 2); // 2 is the id of the google calendar in my phone
event.put("title", "Test Event2");
event.put("description", "Hiii Buddy");
long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000;
event.put("dtstart", startTime);
event.put("dtend", endTime);
event.put("allDay", 0);
event.put("eventStatus", 1);// tentative 0, confirmed 1 canceled 2
event.put("visibility", 3);// default 0 confidential 1 private 2
                            // public 3
event.put("transparency", 0);// opaque 0 transparent 1
event.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 false, 1 true

Uri eventsUri = getCalendarURI(true);
Uri url = getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable sync in: Settings -> Accounts & sync -> Manage accounts -> Sync Calendar
In Calendar application: Menu -> More -> Calendars you have to put your Google account to 'synced'.

Comment: is it possible for emulator or not?